# PHPExcel clear cell comments

Tags: comments, phpexcel

Is it possible to clear all cell comments in PHPExcel before adding a new one? I have working code that adds a comment but I would like to clear all existing comments in a particular cell first:

```
$pexr = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
try {
   $pex = $pexr->load($fn);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
     //...
     return;
   }
}
// ...        
sheet = $pex->getSheetByName($curMed);
...
$sheet->setCellValue($col . $row, $r[7]);
$sheet->getStyle($col . $row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0');
$sheet->getComment($col . $row)->getText()->createText("My lovely comment\r\n");
```

Unfortunately I could not find anything like "clear" in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are stored as an array, indexed by cell address in the worksheet object; and it provides methods to get and set the entire array; so it's perfectly possible to retrieve the array, unset comments for the cell that you want to clear, then put the array back again overwriting the original:

```
$comments = $sheet->getComments();
if (isset($comments[$col . $row])) {
    unset($comments[$col . $row]);
    $sheet->setComments($comments);
}
```